# openssl s_client, GnuTLS, sslscan disagree on supported ciphers

Tags: openssl

**OpenSSL** says the cipher suit for a given webserver is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect 10.87.0.51:12656 </dev/null | grep Cipher
depth=0 C = VE, ST = xxxx, L = xxxxx, O = xxxxx, CN = xxxx.xxx.xx, emailAddress = xxxx@xxxxx.com
verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = VE, ST = xxxxx, L = xxxxx, O = xxxxx, CN = xxxxxx.xx.xx, emailAddress = xxxx@xxxxx.com
verify return:1
DONE
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
```

**GnuTLS** agrees AFAIK (not sure about how to interpret the AES CBC part since it uses a different nomenclature)

```
$ gnutls-cli --no-ca-verification -p 12656 10.87.0.51 < /dev/null | sed -n '/Description/,$p'
- Description: (TLS1.2)-(ECDHE-RSA-SECP256R1)-(AES-128-CBC)-(SHA1)
- Session ID: 5B:B6:66:65:8F:82:29:8B:5C:45:50:29:2F:6C:2D:7A:2C:C8:C0:EE:EB:CC:B7:79:19:1C:26:EA:97:CA:D6:A9
- Ephemeral EC Diffie-Hellman parameters
 - Using curve: SECP256R1
 - Curve size: 256 bits
- Version: TLS1.2
- Key Exchange: ECDHE-RSA
- Server Signature: RSA-SHA256
- Cipher: AES-128-CBC
- MAC: SHA1
- Compression: NULL
- Options: safe renegotiation,
- Handshake was completed

- Simple Client Mode:
```

But **SSLscan / openssl** says it failed when testing:

```
$ sslscan 10.87.0.51:12656 | grep -e Accepted -e ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
    Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
    Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
    Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  AES128-SHA
    Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA
    Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  RC4-SHA
    Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  RC4-MD5
    Accepted  TLSv1  112 bits  ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
    Accepted  TLSv1  112 bits  DES-CBC3-SHA
```

Am I wrong to see a contradiction here? I'm completely new at this.

**Edit**: SSLscan doesn't really send a Server Hello for ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256, but instead connects TCP and disconnnects *twice*, returning                    “SSL routines / ssl3_client_hello / no ciphers available”. I'd need to dig further into SSLscan.

Answer (score 0):

During the initial TLS handshake a client sends a **Client Hello** message which contains amongst other things a version number, compression method requested, extensions (such as SNI) and importantly in this case, a list of cipher suites that the client supports.

The server responds with a **Server Hello** message, which containts various elements, including the server certificate, an optional request for a client certificate, and importantly, the chosen chipher suite selected from the list the client previously submitted.

In your example, the server is fixed and the client change.  Therefore the different cipher suite selected is down to the different capabilities of your clients.

Comment: Even with the same library and no additional configuration on my part? Tomorrow I'll capture the handshakes and look for the difference in suites sent in Client Hello.

Comment: That's the best way to investigate.  OpenSSL and GnuTLS are different libraries.  Is SSLScan statically linked to a different OpenSSL library?  I've just tried OpenSSL and SSLScan and got the same ciphers for both.

Comment: Having dug a little deeper, it seems that my version of SSLScan uses OpenSSL 1.0.2l while `openssl version` shows 1.1.0f.

Comment: Mine both use the same .so (confirmed by `ldd`), but somehow `sslscan` doesn't send the Server Hello for ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256. `openssl version` and `dpkg -l libssl1.0.0` say it's 1.0.2g.